# How to randomly create a preference dataframe from a dataframe of choices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, random

I have a Dataframe of vote and I would like to create one of preferences.
For example here is the number of votes for each party P1, P2, P3 in each city Comm, Comm2 ...

```
    Comm    Votes   P1      P2      P3
0   comm1   1315.0  2.0     424.0   572.0
1   comm2   4682.0  117.0   2053.0  1584.0
2   comm3   2397.0  2.0     40.0    192.0
3   comm4   931.0   2.0     12.0    345.0
4   comm5   842.0   47.0    209.0   76.0
... ... ... ... ... ...
1524    comm1525    10477.0 13.0    673.0   333.0
1525    comm1526    2674.0  1.0 55.0    194.0
1526    comm1527    1691.0  331.0   29.0    78.0
```

These electoral results would suffice for a *first pass the ballot system*, I would like to test [the alternative election model](https://www.electoral-reform.org.uk/voting-systems/types-of-voting-system/alternative-vote/). So for each political party I need to get the preferences.

As I don't know the preferences, I want to make them with random numbers. I suppose that voters are honest. For example, for the "P1" party in town "comm" We know that 2 people voted for it and that there are 1315 voters. I need to create preferences to see if people would put it as their first, second or third option. It is to say, and for each party:

```
     Comm      Votes    P1_1        P1_2    P1_3    P2_1    P2_2    P2_3    P3_1     P3_2   P3_3
0    comm1      1315.0  2.0         1011.0  303.0   424.0   881.0   10.0    570.0    1.0    1.0
... ... ... ... ... ...
1526 comm1527   1691.0  331.0   1300.0  60.0    299.0   22.0    10.0    ...
```

So I have to do:

```
# for each column in parties I create (parties -1) other columns
# I rename them all Party_i. The former 1 becomes Party_1.
# In the other columns I put a random number. 
# For a given line, the sum of all Party_i for i in [1, parties] mus t be equal to Votes
```

I tried this so far:

```py
parties = [item for item in df.columns if item not in ['Comm','Votes']]

for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    # In the other columns I put a random number. 
    for party in parties:
        # for each column in parties I create (parties -1) other columns
        for i in range(0,len(parties) -1):
            print(random.randrange(0, row['Votes']))
            # I rename them all Party_i. The former 1 becomes Party_1. 
            row["{party}_{preference}".format(party = party,preference = i)] = random.randrange(0, row['Votes']) if (row[party] < row['Votes']) else 0 # false because the sum of the votes isn't = to df['Votes']
```

The results are:

```
     Comm      Votes    ... P1_1    P1_2   P1_3    P2_1    P2_2    P2_3    P3_1     P3_2   P3_3
0    comm1      1315.0  ... 1003    460    1588    1284    1482    1613    1429   345
1    comm2      1691.0  ... 1003    460    1588    1284    1482    1613    ...  
...
```

But:

1. the numbers are the same for each rows
2. the value in row of `Pi_1` isn't equal to the one in the row of `Pi` (`Pi` being a given party).
3. the sum of `Pi_j` for all j in [0, parties] isn't equal to the number in the column `Votes`

## Update

I tried Antihead's answer with his own data and it worked well. But when apllying to my own data it doesn't. It leaves me an empty dataframe:

```
import collections

def fill_cells(cell):
    v_max = cell['Votes']
    all_dict = {}
    #iterate over parties.copy()
    for p in parties:
        tmp_l = parties.copy()
        tmp_l.remove(p)
        # sample new data with equal choices
        sampled = np.random.choice(tmp_l, int(v_max-cell[p]))
        # transform into dictionary
        c_sampled = dict(collections.Counter(sampled))
        c_sampled.update({p:cell[p]})
        # batch update of the dictio~nary keys
        all_dict.update(
            dict(zip([p+'_%s' %k[1] for k in c_sampled.keys()], c_sampled.values()))
            )
    return pd.Series(all_dict)
```

Indeed, with the following dataframe:

```
    Comm    Votes   LPC     CPC     BQ
0   comm1   1315.0  2.0     424.0   572.0
1   comm2   4682.0  117.0   2053.0  1584.0
2   comm3   2397.0  2.0     40.0    192.0
3   comm4   931.0   2.0     12.0    345.0
4   comm5   842.0   47.0    209.0   76.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1522    comm1523    23808.0     1588.0  4458.0  13147.0
1523    comm1524    639.0   40.0    126.0   40.0
1524    comm1525    10477.0     13.0    673.0   333.0
1525    comm1526    2674.0  1.0     55.0    194.0
1526    comm1527    1691.0  331.0   29.0    78.0
```

I have an empty dataframe:

```
0
1
2
3
4
...
1522
1523
1524
1525
1526
```

Comment: Are You able to reformulate the question for a better understanding?
Do You want to e.g. compute the chance of one person in an unknown community give its vote to P1, P2, P3 ?

Comment: @Antihead Sure. For example if we take comm1 (which gives the row),  and a party P1,  I just want random numbers in each cell P1_i for i in [1,number of parties], their sum must be equal to Votes and P1_1 must be equal to P1. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do i understand correctly: 
For each cell:
    You want to partition the leftover votes: `|Votes|-P_i`, to `P_{j}` `j element from [1,2,3] where i!=j`
? (with a random chance)

Comment: @Antihead,  yes ! P_{j} being random and meaning the number of votes for party P

Comment: `tmp_l = parties` does not copy Your list, but references it.
You need to copy the list instead
`tmp_l = parties,copy()`

Comment: @Antihead isn't it `parties.copy()`? Further more I tried with actual party names and leave the dataframe empty

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```py
# data
columns = ['Comm', 'Votes', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3']
data =[['comm1', 1315.0, 2.0, 424.0, 572.0],
['comm2', 4682.0, 117.0, 2053.0, 1584.0],
['comm3', 2397.0, 2.0, 40.0, 192.0],
['comm4', 931.0, 2.0, 12.0, 345.0],
['comm5', 842.0, 47.0, 209.0, 76.0],
['comm1525', 10477.0, 13.0, 673.0, 333.0],
['comm1526', 2674.0, 1.0, 55.0, 194.0],
['comm1527', 1691.0, 331.0, 29.0, 78.0]]


df =pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

import collections

def fill_cells(cell):
    v_max = cell['Votes']
    all_dict = {}
    #iterate over parties
    for p in ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']:
        tmp_l = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']
        tmp_l.remove(p)
        # sample new data with equal choices
        sampled = np.random.choice(tmp_l, int(v_max-cell[p]))
        # transform into dictionary
        c_sampled = dict(collections.Counter(sampled))
        c_sampled.update({p:cell[p]})
        # batch update of the dictionary keys
        all_dict.update(
            dict(zip([p+'_%s' %k[1] for k in c_sampled.keys()], c_sampled.values()))
            )
    return pd.Series(all_dict)
# get back a data frame
df.apply(fill_cells, axis=1)
```

If You need to merge the data frame back, do something like:

```py
new_df = df.apply(fill_cells, axis=1)
pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I get `ValueError: ('negative dimensions are not allowed', 'occurred at index 0')` and `KeyError: ('PI_3', 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: Do You use python3 ? Try using the data frame which i defined in my answer first, to see if the code runs. (i have no trouble running it. ..)

Comment: Yes, I use python3 and I tried your dataframe. I have updated my question with my attempt on your answer

Comment: Many thanks, your code works now! However the name of the headers are `P1_P1, P1_P2, P1_P3, P2_P1, ...` and I was looking to rather create `P1_1, P1_2, ...` in order to express preferences. For instance `P1_2` would be the column of the number of people who would have selected party `P1` as their second choice. I'm working on using your code for this purpose at the moment but I haven't achieved it yet

Comment: I adjusted the code accordingly the expression `p+'_%s' %k[1]` gives You now Pi_j instead of Pi_Pj

Comment: If You are happy with the answer now, please accept it as such :)

Comment: Actually I'm still struggling as I can't apply it to actual party names as it leaves an empty dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Based on Antihead's answer and for the following dataset:

```
    Comm    Votes   LPC     CPC     BQ
0   comm1   1315.0  2.0     424.0   572.0
1   comm2   4682.0  117.0   2053.0  1584.0
2   comm3   2397.0  2.0     40.0    192.0
3   comm4   931.0   2.0     12.0    345.0
4   comm5   842.0   47.0    209.0   76.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1522    comm1523    23808.0     1588.0  4458.0  13147.0
1523    comm1524    639.0   40.0    126.0   40.0
1524    comm1525    10477.0     13.0    673.0   333.0
1525    comm1526    2674.0  1.0     55.0    194.0
1526    comm1527    1691.0  331.0   29.0    78.0
```

I tried:

```py
def fill_cells(cell):
    votes_max = cell['Votes']
    all_dict = {}
    #iterate over parties
    parties_temp = parties.copy()
    for p in parties_temp:
        preferences = ['1','2','3']
        for preference in preferences:
            preferences.remove(preference)
            # sample new data with equal choices
            sampled = np.random.choice(preferences, int(votes_max-cell[p])) 
            # transform into dictionary
            c_sampled = dict(collections.Counter(sampled))
            c_sampled.update({p:cell[p]})
            c_sampled['1'] = c_sampled.pop(p)
            # batch update of the dictionary keys
            all_dict.update(
                dict(zip([p+'_%s' %k for k in c_sampled.keys()],c_sampled.values()))
            )
    return pd.Series(all_dict)
```

It returns

```py
    LPC_2   LPC_3   LPC_1   CPC_2   CPC_3   CPC_1   BQ_2    BQ_3    BQ_1
    0   891.0   487.0   424.0   743.0   373.0   572.0   1313.0  683.0   2.0
    1   2629.0  1342.0  2053.0  3098.0  1603.0  1584.0  4565.0  2301.0  117.0
    2   2357.0  1186.0  40.0    2205.0  1047.0  192.0   2395.0  1171.0  2.0
    3   919.0   451.0   12.0    586.0   288.0   345.0   929.0   455.0   2.0
    4   633.0   309.0   209.0   766.0   399.0   76.0    795.0   396.0   47.0
    ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
    1520    1088.0  536.0   42.0    970.0   462.0   160.0   1117.0  540.0   13.0
    1521    4742.0  2341.0  219.0   3655.0  1865.0  1306.0  4705.0  2375.0  256.0
    1522    19350.0     9733.0  4458.0  10661.0     5352.0  13147.0     22220.0     11100.0     1588.0
    1523    513.0   264.0   126.0   599.0   267.0   40.0    599.0   306.0   40.0
    1524    9804.0  4885.0  673.0   10144.0     5012.0  333.0   10464.0     5162.0  13.0
```

It's almost good. I would have prefered the preferences to be dynamically encoded rather than to hard code `['1','2','3']`.